# Best front end software manager for local queries

Tags: open-source, microsoft-access, libreoffice

I am starting a little personal project and looking for a front end manager.  I was previously using Microsoft Access but ran into the 2 gig limit and decided to move to a new software.  I have looked at libre base and kexi but wanted to get any suggestions.  I have limited skills in sql and limited to no experience in the database management.

The project is going to run on my desktop (linux) and only accessed locally on that machine.  The data sets will imported from csv files and will have minimum 90,000 entries.  It will be names, addresses, and need to be queried against lists of zip codes as a start and then that list queried against other criteria before exported to an excel spreadsheet.

I am not opposed to paying for software if it makes it extremely easy, but as its a personal project less is more when it comes to cost.

Hoping people might have other suggestions outside those 2 which would work for my situation.  Thanks in advance